# Java: error when trying to break while loop

Tags: java

I keep getting this error when the program is supposed to reach break:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
    at Glosor.main(Glosor.java:65)"

This is the code:

```
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.LinkedList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.io.*;

  public class Glosor {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  List<String> gloslista1 = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList());
  List<String> gloslista2 = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList());

  String inputStr1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                               "**********************************" + "\n\n" + 
                                               "1. Skapa glosövning" + "\n\n" + 
                                               "2. Starta glosövning" + "\n\n" +
                                               "3. Avsluta" + "\n\n" + 
                                               "**********************************");

  int input1 = Integer.parseInt(inputStr1);




     switch (input1) {

        case 1:

        String övningsnamn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Vad heter övningen?");
        String språk1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Språk 1?");      
        String språk2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Språk 2?");

           while (true) {

           String glosa1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Skriv in glosa på " + språk1 + "\n\n" + 
                                                             "När du är klar skriv klar i rutan");               
              if(glosa1.equals("klar")) {
              break;
              //this is where i get the error message
              }
              else {          
              String glosa2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Skriv in glosa på " + språk2); 


              gloslista1.add(glosa1);
              gloslista2.add(glosa2);
              }                      

           }
              String filnamn1 = "svenskaord";
              String filnamn2 = "franskaord";

              PrintWriter utström1 = new PrintWriter
                                     (new BufferedWriter
                                     (new FileWriter(filnamn1)));
              //Skapar en text fil för glosorna på svenska

              PrintWriter utström2 = new PrintWriter
                                     (new BufferedWriter
                                     (new FileWriter(filnamn2)));
              //Skapar en text fil för glosorna på franska   

                 for(int i = 0; i<=gloslista1.size(); i++) {
                 utström1.println(gloslista1.get(i));
                 utström2.println(gloslista2.get(i));
                 //Skriver in glosor i text filerna

                 }
```

Comment: Please provide more code. Currently, is not possible to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Loop should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<=gloslista1.size()-1; i++)
```

means it should end to `gloslista1.size()-1`.The stacktrace is saying that you have 2 element in list so you have 2 indexes in the list ie `0 and 1` but you are trying to access index `2` which is not present in the list giving you the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This for loop is going out of bounds.

```
for(int i = 0; i<=gloslista1.size(); i++) {
    utström1.println(gloslista1.get(i));
    utström2.println(gloslista2.get(i));
    //Skriver in glosor i text filerna

}
```

Doing `gloslista1.get(i)` when `i` is equal to `gloslista1.size()` is out of bounds since the list indices go from 0 to `gloslista1.size()-1`. The for loop needs to be as singhakash suggested, or more idiomatically like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i<gloslista1.size(); i++)
```